# Recovering encrypted home dir password

Tags: mount, password, encryption, data-recovery

When installing Ubuntu some 5 years ago on my laptop I chose to encrypt my home dir.

Now my laptop broke down and I would like to recover the data. I can still login and my home dir gets decrypted with my ubuntu login password.

I have lost my MOUNT password, and my encryption passphrase. How can I recover these? I would like to use the current disk in a HDD enclosure and use it as an external USB disk on my new laptop, and then selectively copy files from there to the new laptop.

I have tried several instructions but so far have failed to get the desired result. I don't fully understand the procedure, and the different levels involved in this process.

Comment: it is nearly impossible to recover encryption passwords.If yo can still mount it from the riginal OS, then copy files from there to an uncrypted drive. Once data is recovered then you can redo the encryption on the new system.

Comment: PS - I don't think knowing the passphrase would help. If I am correct, the passphrase and decryption key are stored in the default keyring of the system that encrypted the drive. This prevents some that knows your passphrase from taking the drive to another computer and opening it. This also means you lose access to the drive if ubuntu is reinstalled unless you can recover the original keyring.

Answer (score 0):

I found and answer to my own question:

Giving the command `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` will ask for "Passphrase". This is misleading. It is NOT asking for any passphrase, but actually your Ubuntu login password. Once you give it, the command will display a hashed-looking string, which is actually your decryption passphrase.

Once displayed, this can be saved to a file, for instance on a USB stick. With the key now on the stick, one can remove the hard drive from the broken laptop, and insert it to a new system, and take the decryption passphrase from the file on the USB stick.